# List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> + Lightning component - Sending emails from a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, apex-email-service

I am getting an error message that the email messaging method is not enabled for Aura components. Need sone help if I am going in the right direction or not.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to allow DML? Not allowed by default on VF components. Not sure about aura.

Comment: Can you pls add your code in question ?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?
Setup -> Email Administration -> Deliverability -> Access to Send Email -> All email

Comment: Yes, the access level is defaulted to All email.